# Bootstrap Row/Container is cut off when columns expand to new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a *mobile-first* header. I have a single `div class="row"` with 4 columns on a single line for viewports of `md, lg`, but when the viewport drops to `sm, xs` I push 2 columns to a new row, and at this point the `row` and/or `fluid-container` does not resize (grow in height) causing a cut-off that only shows the top two columns.

Is there a way to prevent this, or to tell Bootstrap 3's `row` or `container` to grow?

*Customer and total are cut off on xs and sm views, the gray area is a new div with the main page's content*: [image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Sales Order # -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 sp-sales-order">
      <div ng-controller="tabTitleCtrl">
        <div class="sp-header-text">
          {{subtitle}}
        </div>
        <div>
          {{title}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button Block -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 sp-sales-button">
      <div ng-include="toolbarPath">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Totals -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6 col-md-2 col-md-push-4 sp-sales-total">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 sp-header-text">
          Total
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {{Total | currency}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Customer Input Box -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-pull-6 sp-sales-customer">
      <div ng-include="headerPath"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you use any other css except bootstrap? Also can you post not an html template with `ng-include` but the generated html with all data binded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I built it from scratch to get away from the extra classes in your code so you could clearly see what's going on. I'm basically just relying on Bootstrap to stack the cols for me at different display widths - without overdoing the classes.

I *think* this is what you're going for.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/dwmrth0t/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            Invoice
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Void</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Post</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            Totals
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```